# checking the diffeomorphism between 2 surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

I tried to show that a surface $x^4+y^2+z^2=1$ and the unit sphere are diffeomorphic.

Since a diffeomorphism between them is not chosen easily, I would apply a theorem using invertibility of Jacabian.

For this process, I must know a surface patch of $x^4+y^2+z^2=1$, but I don't know that.

Q1. How do I choose the surface patch?

Q2. Is my plan is correct to show that they are diffeomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your manifold $M$.

I'd suggest taking 6 patches,

$$
U_1 : x^2 + y^2 < 0.8, z = \sqrt{1 - (x^2 + y^2)}\\
U_2: x^2 + y^2 < 0.8, z = -\sqrt{1 - (x^2 + y^2)}\\
U_3: y^2 + z^2 < 0.8, x = \sqrt{1 - (y^2 + z^2)}\\
U_4: y^2 + z^2 < 0.8, x = -\sqrt{1 - (y^2 + z^2)}\\
\ldots
$$
on the sphere, and mapping each to your surface with a map like this:

$$
f_1 : U_1 \to M : (x, y, z) \mapsto (sign(x) \sqrt{|x|}, y, z) \\
f_2 : U_2 \to M : (x, y, z) \mapsto (sign(x)\sqrt{|x|}, y, x) \\
\ldots
f_4: U_4 \to M: (x, y, z) \mapsto (sign(x) \sqrt{|x|}, y, x) \\
\ldots
$$
where $sign(x)$ is $+1$ for positive $x$, $-1$ for negative $x$ and zero for $x = 0$.

The maps $f_i$ together constitute a diffeomorphism, I believe.

Actually, on reflection, they don't -- the derivative of the $x^2$ when $x = 0$ is going to make the differential be singular along that equator. Here's a replacement answer:

To map $M$ to $S^2$, define $r(x, y, z) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$. Then define
$$
G: M \to S^2 : (x, y, z) \mapsto \frac{1}{r(x, y, z)} (x, y, z). 
$$

That's a diffeomorphism between the two surfaces. By the way, you can show that by checking that it's a diffeomorphism onto each of the six patches $U_i$ that I described.

Comment: what is 0.8 in your answer? and do you mean $f_i$ are patces of $x^4+y^2+z^2=1$?

Comment: $0.8$ is the number $4/5$. The idea is to describe a bit of the sphere a bit smaller than the northern hemisphere. The idea is that six such patches cover the whole sphere, as if you'd drawn a cubical subdivision on the sphere's surface and then fattened each face a bit. 

As for the $f_i$, they together define a map from $S^2$ to $M$. Each point of $S^2$ has the form $(x, y, z)$ where $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. I want to send this to a point $(x', y', z')$ with $x'^4 + y'^2 + z'^2 = 1$. To do so, I take the square root of the $x$-coordinate. (edited answer to fix this)

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence.
The diffeomorphism is a multivariable function. But your $f_i's$ have a domain $U_i$, respectively, and they are not disjoint.

Comment: That's correct. But if you look at a point in the overlap of two different $U_i$s, you'll find that the two different $f_i$s produce exactly the same result, so taken together, they constitute a function on all of $S^2$. This is a typical way to define a function on a manifold: piece by piece, checking the "compatibility condition". It's like defining
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}x^4 & x \ge 0\\
-x^4 & x \le 0
\end{cases}
$$
in a calculus class. There are two different definitions at $x = 0$, but since they produce the same answer, the definition is valid.

Comment: Oh I see. At first, I tried as your method. But, I was not sure it is correct.
By the way, how do you calculate the map G?
Do you find it just as the equiareal in Archimedes' theorem?

Comment: No...it's just radial projection from the ellipsoid-like-shape $M$ to the sphere $S^2$. We know that every point $P$ of $S^2$ has $r(P) = 1$, so for a point $Q$ of $M$, dividing $Q$ by $r(Q)$ gets a point on the sphere. @Ted Shifrin's answer below summarizes all this quite compactly.

Comment: Ok...By the way, does your map $r$ mean $\|x\|$?
If then, is the correct definition $r(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$?

Comment: I'll fix that immediately. Good catch!

Answer (score 3):

Let $M=\{(x,y,z): x^4+y^2+z^2=1\}$. The (radial projection) map $F\colon \Bbb R^3-\{0\}\to S^2$ given by $F(x) = x/\|x\|$ is smooth, hence restricts to a smooth map $f\colon M\to S^2$. It is easy to check that $f$ is a bijection. You can then prove that it is a diffeomorphism by noting that for any $p\in M$, $$T_pM\cap \{tp: t\in\Bbb R\}=\{0\} \tag{$\star$}$$ (i.e., $T_pM$ is transverse to the line spanned by $p$), and so $\ker df_p = \ker dF_p\cap T_pM = \{0\}$. Thus, by the inverse function theorem, $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, and we're done.

**EDIT**: I guess I should elaborate a bit on the claim ($\star$). If $p=(a,b,c)$, the normal vector to $T_pM$ is $(2a^3,b,c)$. If the line spanned by $p$ were contained in $T_pM$, we'd have $(2a^3,b,c)\cdot (a,b,c) = 0$, which leads us to the system
\begin{align*}
2a^4+b^2+c^2&=0 \\ a^4+b^2+c^2&=1
\end{align*}
This means $a^4=-1$, which has no solutions.

It is my suggestion (whenever possible) to avoid explicit chart-checking and to work with the implicit representation of the manifold.

Comment: This is the answer!

Comment: I agree completely with Ted in general, but sometimes, for beginning students, I favor the chart-based approach so that they can see how it all works out. Usually the answer is "really tediously," and being able to learn/use methods like the one shown here is very valuable.

Comment: @John: Sorta like doing constrained max/min problems by parametrizing instead of proving Lagrange multipliers? I agree that students need to know the use of charts, but I do not agree that this is one of them. ... To elaborate on my taste, I prefer to work with (and teach) the calculus of maps $f\colon M\to\Bbb P^n$ by lifting the maps and differentiating $\tilde f\colon M\to \Bbb R^{n+1}$ or $\Bbb C^{n+1}$, yet again avoiding charts.

Answer (score -1):

It is obvious that the map sending $x$ to $\pm x^2$ defines diffeomorphisms between the upper and the lower hemispheres of your surfaces. You just need to check that things are OK on the equator. Can you?

A different way is to check that both surfaces are strictly convex, then they are diffeomrophic.

Comment: Do you mean that $f_1(x,y,z)=(x^2,y,z), f_2(x,y,z)=(-x^2,y,z)$ constitute a diffeomorphism?
Also, you mean I should to check that at x=0?

Comment: I don't believe that this is a diffeomorphism, @Igor Rivin. Look in 2D: you're saying that the restriction of the map $(x, y) \mapsto (sign(x) x^2, y)$ to the set $M$ where $x^4 + y^2 = 1$ is a diffeomorphism. But look at the tangent vector $(0, 1)$ to $M$ at the point $(1, 0)$. The derivative of your map, applied to that tangent vector, is $(0, 0)$. [I'm sad to say I made the same mistake; see my fix near the bottom of my answer below.]